# Why does Google Colab Pro say I have too many sessions, when I currently have only one session running?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I remember that Colab Pro allows you to run 3 sessions at a time. Currently I have only one session running and when I want to run one more session it says I have too many sessions

Answer (score 0):

There's already several angry people complaining here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues